# How do I pass an argument that was passed to main (in argv) to my function?

Tags: c++

How can i pass argv[] to my function?, I am getting the errors when I run my program. I am new to c++ but i think i am not passing it right look at the error and my code. Now dont worry about the Depth First algorithm.. i will get to that later.. I am just trying to make this work.., basically I just want to pass the *argv[] to evaluate them in my printDepthFirst() but something is not right (obviously) .. Thank you

```
myprogram.c: In function ‘main’:
myprogram.c:18:4: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘opendir’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
/usr/include/dirent.h:135:13: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char
```

code

Comment: If you are new to C++, I suggest you learn C++, instead of learning C. A [good introductory book](http://tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks), perhaps?

Comment: I really see no point in avoiding the use a library (eg. boost.filesystem) to do that with minimal code.

Comment: cant use boost ...Awoodland got it .. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to write `opendir(arg_temp)`. `arg_temp[1]` is the *second* character of `arg_temp`. I wouldn't recommend using global variables to pass things to your function though anyway.